# Durandal JS and Google Plus Sign in Javascript API

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-plus, durandal, google-api-js-client

So I'm trying to build a mobile app using Durandal. However, I am having trouble to do so with Google plus JS API integration. I think here is the problem: The javascript client for gapi comes with asynchronous loading, so durandal initialization will crash having gapi undefined and because of this, the css components also do not render properly also. I have tried putting the following script tags in the login.html file of my view for login.js or even in the require.js section of my main.js but it's still not working. Scripts for linking to Google Api:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer>    </script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>

//onSignInCallBack function to call in login.js after user signs in vis Google Plus
onSignInCallback: function(authResult) {
                    gapi.client.load('plus','v1').then(function() {

                        if (authResult['access_token']) {
                            $('#authOps').show('slow');
                            $('#gConnect').hide();
                            var user_access_token = authResult['access_token'];
                            var id_token = authResult['id_token'];
                        } else if (authResult['error']) {
                            // There was an error, which means the user is not signed in.
                            console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
                            $('#authOps').hide('slow');
                            $('#gConnect').show();
                        }
                        console.log('authResult', authResult);
                    });
                },
```

Here is my main.js file:

```
    requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
        'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
        'knockout' : '../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0',
        'bootstrap': '../Scripts/bootstrap',
        'jquery':'../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1',
        'async':'../Scripts/async'
    }
});


define(['durandal/system',
        'durandal/app',
        'durandal/viewLocator',
        'durandal/binder',
        'utils/routines',
        'async!https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback',
        'async!https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js'

], function (system, app, viewLocator, binder,routines,callback,gapi) {

    //>>excludeStart("build", true);
    system.debug(true);
    //>>excludeEnd("build");

    app.configurePlugins({
        router: true,
        dialog: true,
        widget: true
    });

    app.start().then(function() {
        //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
        //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
        viewLocator.useConvention();

        //Show the app by setting the root view model for our application with a transition.
        app.setRoot('shell/shell', 'entrance');

        // override bad route behavior to write to 
        // console log and show error toast
        /*
        router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
            logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
        };
        */
    });
});
```

Here is my index.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/Content/images/ios-startup-image-    landscape.png" media="(orientation:landscape)" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/Content/images/ios-startup-image-portrait.png" media="(orientation:portrait)" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="~/Content/images/icon.png" />
    <link href="/Content/ie10mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/durandal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/starterkit.css" rel="stylesheet" />   

    <script type="text/javascript">

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
            var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
            var mq = "@@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}";
            msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mq));
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="applicationHost">
        <div class="text-center">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
            <div class="message">
                Loading....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/require.js" data-main="/App/main"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Have anyone ever tried to integrate google plus sign in with Durandal and have this same issue? Help and suggestion is much appreciated!!

Comment: Just so you know, `script` tags on any page other than your initial page are ignored.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought but I couldn't find any other way. So if I'm trying to load an API by calling a url, what's the best way to do this in Durandal? Can I still put the url in the require.js section of the main where I link to my other scripts? Thanks Eric!!

Comment: Also i used the facebook sdk javascript which load asynchronously and it works fine but not for the google plus javascript api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remote async loads under Durandal (or, in other words, under RequireJS), you'll need the async, goog, and propertyParser [plugins](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins).  See the readme at that link.

As an example, here's what we do for Google Maps:

**in the paths property of RequireJS (usually in the main.js file of Durandal), the following order:**

```
'async': '../Scripts/plugins/async',
'propertyParser': '../Scripts/plugins/propertyParser',
'goog': '../Scripts/plugins/goog'
```

**the define, also in the main.js file of Durandal, just before the main function that kicks off the application:**

```
define('jquery', function() { return jQuery; });
define('knockout', ko);
define('gmaps', ['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'],
    function () {            
        return window.google.maps;
    });

define(['durandal/system',
        'durandal/app',
        'durandal/viewLocator',
        'bindings',
        'extenders',
        'validations'],
    function (system, app, viewLocator, bindings, extenders, validations) {
```

Notice the `async!` before the remote API URL.  Also notice that we don't actually define gmaps for the main entry point of the application.  We set up a global define *before* the main entry point.

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: @KendrickLay Could you post your main.js and index.html (or whatever your default page is)? Thanks.

Comment: @KendrickLay O.K.  I did some more research on this.  Just as we have for the the Google Maps API, you're going to need two additional plugins: the **goog** plugin and the **propertyParser** plugin.  I thought those were  required just for the Google Maps.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @KenrickLay Take a look at your `defines`.  I updated my code to show you where they would go, and this makes them globally available for injection throughout your application.  As to the specifics of the API you're using, I can't really help you there.  You may need to use the `goog!` prefix for the API you're using.  Also, you may need to return a global window reference, as we do with Google Maps.  The forum for those plugins might be the best place to post a question.  Just so you know, this is messy business.  But it does work reliably...

Comment: Thanks so much @EricTaylor!! Really appreciate the help, especially coming from an experienced Durandal user like yourself! Will try making those changes now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @KendrickLay You're welcome.  Let's work together to refine my answer so that others looking for an answer on the subject won't have to work as hard.

Comment: @KendrickLay Again, you're welcome! I just voted your answer up.  I'm sure this will minimize the headache for many folks to come.

Comment: I was wondering do you know a good way to approach this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221892/multiple-shells-views-and-view-models-and-routers-for-different-type-of-users Thanks @EricTaylor!

Comment: @KendrickLay I just answered the question you posted there!

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution to integrate the google plus sign in into my Durandal app. You basically need to include asyncJS (don't have to include googJS/propertyParserJS, goog only works for very specific google APIs - (https://developers.google.com/loader/?csw=1#AvailableAPIs) in the require section of main.js and define the google client api in main.js. However, you cannot use the following urls to call the api in your define in main.js.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer>    </script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
```

In the Google Plus Sign In Javascript API documentation, you are asked to include the above script tags in your html file. However, this does not work with requireJS and Async. Instead you need to call Google Client API and use the following url in main.js:

```
        define('gapi',['async!https://apis.google.com/js/client.js!onload'], function() {
        console.log('gapi loaded: ' + gapi);
        return window.gapi;
    });
```

You can then call gapi in your specific viewmodel after doing this by including it in the define section of your viewmodel. To implement the google plus sign in, you can then call the following function after defining and passing in the parameters as specified by the instructions in Google Plus Sign in Javascript API (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow):

```
    define(['gapi'], function(gapi) {
    return {
        additionalParams : {
            'callback': "specify a callback function here",
            'clientid' :"your client_ID",
            'scope' : "scope for permissions",
            'cookiepolicy' : "single_host_origin"
            },


            googlelogin: function() {
                gapi.auth.signIn(this.additionalParams);
            }
    }
    });
```

I then bind the googlelogin method to my google sign in button using 
`data-bind="click:googlelogin"`. This will let you sign in using your google plus after clicking the button. However, this method seems to have a problem when it comes to the callback for me. So here is the second alternative which works for me, use the following method to authorize the user and execute the callback (you must define this)when your sign in button is clicked:

```
gapi.auth.authorize(parameters,signinCallBack);
```

The parameters are specified here: (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorize). Hope this helps you integrate your Durandal/RequireJS app with Google Plus and Ouath2 for client side JS  implementation! Thank you @EricTaylor for guiding me!

Comment: any chance you can post the full main.js script. I've added the define but am not getting anything logged to the console.

Comment: I am trying to implement reCaptcha and this seems promising but not getting it right. If you can post ur main Js or better yet if you have done reCaptcha. thanks

Comment: You can use the gapi.auth.signIn method if you pass the callback function directly to the callback attribute like this:
'callback': onSignIn
If you do it like in your example ('callback': "onSignIn") it just works with global callback functions.